# How to make a correct delay before function executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, animation

So, I'm trying to do a loading animation for my website on ASP.NET WebForms. I have noticed that some pages are loading really fast and some are not. 
I have made an execution of an animation in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

         $('#loadingImage').hide();
         $('#loading').html("");
     });
```

But now I want to make a delay, approximately in 1-2 sec for pages that load fast to not show the animation for them.
I try to do this in this way:

```
setTimeout(checkDocument, 3000);

  function hideLoading() {
      $('#loadingImage').hide();
      $('#loading').html("");
  }

  function checkDocument() {
      $(document).ready(hideLoading);
  };
```

My HTML code:

```
 <div id="loading" style="text-align: center" ><asp:Image ID="loadingImage" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Images/loading.gif" /></div>
```

So, this works wrong. This code executed my animation at once and then off the animation in 3 seconds.
Help to find out the right way for this.
And one more, I have this line of code

```
$('#loading').html("");
```

Why if we not use nothing as argument in html part, then animation can't stop, when we take "" to the html then everything works. Please, explain this moment.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand why do you need such a delay. If a page loads fast, animation will be hidden fastly, so end user won't notice it.

Comment: @hindmost I think so too, but it's unfortunately visible and looks like something that works bad.

Comment: @whoiskatrin : post your html

Comment: You do it in wrong way. You have to delay (by timeout) the code of **animation** itself, not animation hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is make the loading animation invisible at first, and then make it visible after a delay. Finally, use the document.ready event to hide it when everything is loaded. What you're doing right now is just delaying the creation of the document.ready event handler, which makes no sense. (Don't forget, creating an event handler doesn't actually execute the function immediately, it just creates something which listens for the event occurring in the future.)

Change your div definition to

```
<div id="loading" style="text-align: center" hidden>
```

It should be the first thing that's put into the `<body>` section of your page, if possible.

Then, immediately below it, put the following script tag:

```
<script>
  function showLoading() {
    $("#loading").show();
  }

  var loadingTimeout = setTimeout(showLoading, 3000);

  $(document).ready(function() {
    clearTimeout(loadingTimeout); //make sure loader doesn't appear if page loads in less than 3 seconds
    $("#loading").hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.